# RegExp - How can I match the shortest amount possible?

Tags: javascript, regex, or-operator

I have my Regular Expression `/'(.*)(?:(?:'\s*,\s*)|(?:'\)))/`
and my test code `('He said, "You're cool."' , 'Rawr')`
(My test code simulates parameters being passed into a function.) 

I will explain my Regular Expression as I understand it and hopefully a few of you can shed some light on my problem. 
1)`/'` means at the beginning of the matched string, there needs to be `'` 
2)`(.*)` means capture any character except `\n` 0 or more times 
3)`(?:(?:4)|(?:5))` means don't capture but try to do step 4 and if it doesn't work try step 5 
4)`(?:'\s*,\s*)` means don't capture but there needs to be a `'` with 0 or more whitespace characters followed by a `,` with 0 or more whitespace characters 
5)`(?:'\))` means don't capture but there needs to be `')` 
So it seems that it should return this (and this is what I want): 
`'`+`He said, "You're cool."`+`' ,` 
But it returns: 
`'`+`He said, "You're cool."' , 'Rawr`+`')` 
If I change my test code to `('He said, "You're cool."' , 'Rawr'` (no end parenthesis) it returns what I want, but as soon as I add that last parenthesis, then it seems that my OR operator does whatever it wants to. I want it to test first if there is a comma, and break there if there is one, and if there is not one check for a parenthesis. 
I've tried switching the spots of step 4 and step 5, but still the OR operator seems to always default to the `(?:'\))` side. 
**How can I match the shortest amount possible?**

Comment: Beginning of string would be `/^`, not `/`, fwiw. Personally I'm not convinced I'd use a regex for what it is you're trying to do, but rather a small parser. Confusing regex is confusing.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yes I know that. That's why I said at the beginning of the matched string. Maybe I should've said at the beginning of the matched portion of the string. Or when it starts the match it needs to begin with a `'`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think your problem is the OR operator, but the [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) of the `.*`. It will match your full string, and then *back*-track until the following expressions match. The first match in this backtracking process will be `'He said, "You're cool."' , 'Rawr`+`')`. Try `.*?` instead!